# How to use windows set command with cygwin sed on RHS

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cygwin, cmd

Typing this from a command prompt works:

```
pwd | sed "s/\/cygdrive\/c/c:/"
```

I want to use it on the RHS of set

This does not work:

```
set ztmp =(pwd | (sed "s/\/cygdrive\/c/c:/")
```

Specifically no errors or warnings are returned and the var ztemp is not defined.
For this little ditty I am only typing in the commands.

Windows 7 cmd prompt with Cygvwin installed.

There is probably something I don't understand about the general case of controlling the expansion.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the `cygpath` command for converting paths to/from in Cyg.

Comment: added extra tags to attract cmd/microsoft monkeys, I am a bash/gnu/linux monkey.

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash you can do this, but not in cmd.

```
ztmp=$(pwd | sed "s/\/cygdrive\/c/c:/")
```

Comment: I cut and pasted the answer.  Windows replied ztmp = $(pwd | sed "s/\/cygdrive\/c/c:/")
'ztmp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: OK, but not an option to use bash this time.  Thanks Mike

Comment: Have similar issues putting results from a cygpath run into a windows var.  For example set znew =(cygpath -w "%SYNP_PATH%") results in this znew =(cygpath -w "c:\Program Files (x86)\Synplicity\fpga_962\bin") (I just typed set to see the value).

Comment: Every where I look, if it has an answer it says `For /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (command) Do Set MyVar=%%A`. I can't get it to work. But then Microsoft os is hard, that is why there are so many users, it takes that many to get the job done.